# Is there a faster way to obtain the most recent line?

Tags: awk, zsh

I am trying to obtain the most recent entry for each IP address - second column - by using the date in column 3 from data.csv. Currently I am using a for loop with a sort & grep, but my actual data.csv has over 9000 lines, and this process takes over an hour to complete. I am looking for a faster method to parse this data (possibly AWK?)

data.csv:

```
110095,10.185.10.53,2020-01-07 03:00:57
110095,10.185.10.53,2019-11-06 09:22:02
110095,10.185.12.15,2019-09-23 09:03:24
110095,10.185.12.15,2019-09-23 09:03:24
110095,10.185.12.16,2020-01-07 03:00:57
110095,10.185.12.16,2019-12-20 09:18:57
110095,10.185.12.31,2019-02-07 08:13:35
110095,10.185.12.31,2019-12-20 09:18:57
110095,10.185.12.31,2020-01-07 03:00:57
110095,10.185.12.32,2019-09-23 09:03:24
110095,10.185.12.32,2019-12-20 09:18:57
110095,10.185.12.32,2019-11-06 09:22:02
```

Current process being used:

```
UNIQUE=$(awk -F, '{print $2}' "/C/Temp/data.csv" | sort -t, -k2 | uniq)

for dest in $UNIQUE; do
    grep ,${dest}, "/C/Temp/data.csv"  | tr , ' ' | sort -k3 -k4 | tail -1 >> /C/temp/Latest.csv
done
```

Latest.csv:

```
110095 10.185.10.53 2020-01-07 03:00:57
110095 10.185.12.15 2019-09-23 09:03:24
110095 10.185.12.16 2020-01-07 03:00:57
110095 10.185.12.31 2020-01-07 03:00:57
110095 10.185.12.32 2019-12-20 09:18:57
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what the "most recent entry for each line" is. Most recent in which set of lines? Most recent among the lines that share the first two fields?

Comment: Each IP (column 2) I need the most recent record for it (column 3)

Comment: Does the output have to be ordered by the IP address field?

Comment: Why not just `sort -r file | awk -F, 'p!=$2{print;p=$2}'`?

Comment: @BenjaminW.No, as long as I get the most recent values, I am good

Comment: @oguzismail That worked! Brilliant!

Answer (score 2):

You could do a single pass in awk to store the most recent entry for each IP address:

```
awk -F, '     
    $3 > times[$2] {
        times[$2] = $3
        $1 = $1            # Self-assign to get rid of input commas
        out[$2] = $0
    }
    END {
        for (ip in out) {
            print out[ip]
        }
    }
' data.csv
```

This might change the sequence in which the IP addresses show up, though.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to preserve the sorted order of  the IP addresses if the records are not already sorted by IP and time in either ascending or descending order. However, you can preserve the order using GNU awk to sort the final record indexes before outputting the saved record values.

Additionally, as long as you are using GNU awk, you can create a timestamp from each of the date/time values (converted to seconds since epoch) and make the IP record comparison on that basis).

You can do that with the following:

```
awk -F, '{ 
        dtspec=$3                   # save date/time values from 3rd field
        gsub(/[-:]/," ",dtspec)     # remove '-' and ':' to create datespec
        tmspec=mktime(dtspec)       # create timespec from datespec w/mktime
        if (tmspec > ip[$2]) {      # compare timespec w/current for IP
            $1 = $1                 # remove field separators
            rec[$2]=$0              # store modified record
            ip[$2]=tmspec           # update timespec for ip
        }
    }
END {
    n = asorti (rec, sorted)        # sort rec by index into sorted
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++)            # loop over sorted indexes
        print rec[sorted[i]]        # outputting records by sorted indexes
}' data.csv
```

**Example Use/Output**

For testing you can copy/middle-mouse-paste into an xterm set to the directory containing your file.

```
$ awk -F, '{
>         dtspec=$3                   # save date/time values from 3rd field
>         gsub(/[-:]/," ",dtspec)     # remove '-' and ':' to create datespec
>         tmspec=mktime(dtspec)       # create timespec from datespec w/mktime
>         if (tmspec > ip[$2]) {      # compare timespec w/current for IP
>             $1 = $1                 # remove field separators
>             rec[$2]=$0              # store modified record
>             ip[$2]=tmspec           # update timespec for ip
>         }
>     }
> END {
>     n = asorti (rec, sorted)        # sort rec by index into sorted
>     for (i=1; i<=n; i++)            # loop over sorted indexes
>         print rec[sorted[i]]        # outputting records by sorted indexes
> }' data.csv
110095 10.185.10.53 2020-01-07 03:00:57
110095 10.185.12.15 2019-09-23 09:03:24
110095 10.185.12.16 2020-01-07 03:00:57
110095 10.185.12.31 2020-01-07 03:00:57
110095 10.185.12.32 2019-12-20 09:18:57
```

If you don't need to preserve the sorted IP order -- then the answer [@BenjaminW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3266847/benjamin-w) is by far your best and most portable bet.